# how to test for collision only if object is moving fast in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

Currently I am testing against collisionImpulse and it works 95% of the time, but every once in a while the object goes right through the sprite at the same speed but returns a way larger number. I want the two objects to collide if moving slowly but trigger an action if moving fast.

This is what I'm doing now

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if(contact.bodyB.node?.name == "sprite" && contact.bodyA.node?.name == "object") {
        if(contact.collisionImpulse > 3e-5){
```

My output of collisionImpulse looks like:

0.317869

0.285309

0.899219

0.0272814

0.325666

6.4235e-09

the last is the one that went right through but appeared the same on screen as the others.

one I want to bounce off looks like

1.71999e-07

Am I missing something somewhere else? or is there a better way to test that produces more consistent results?

Comment: Are you checking the case where `contact.bodyB.node?.name` is "object" and `contact.bodyA.node?.name` is "sprite"?

Comment: I am... I separated them to see if that was part of the issue earlier.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might want to look into is a property called "Newtonian Seconds"  each SKContact (inside your "didbegincontact" method) will have this value.  Basically this ends up representing how hard the collision was.  So if its a bullet then it will be really high, however if it is a tap from someone else the value will be very low.

Personally I would actually be doing this by category, and test bit masks.  Basically what you do is you make a UInt32 variable for each category of object and set it equal to (0x01 << x) (where x is any number that is unique).  And then what you do is set the test bitmask to the objects you want to have SKContacts for when they hit.  Sorta like this.

```
var c_Ball:UInt32 = (0x01 << 1)
var c_Fairy:UInt32 = (0x01 << 2)
var c_Human:UInt32 = (0x01 << 3)

var humantestbitmask = c_Fairy | c_Ball //SKPhysics contacts will only be made when the player hits a ball or fairy, not another human.
```

Comment: is there a way to tell with bit masks how hard the player hits the ball? or do I fall back to Newtonian seconds either way.

Comment: Either way Newtonian seconds is probably what you want.  Why dont you try printing the newtonian seconds of each contact and see if it will fit what you need.